# Any suggestions for M1 optimized file comparison tool?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, apple-silicon

I installed kdiff3 on my m1 mac using homebrew but it seems that it doesn't have an apple m1 optimized version and hence takes 2-3 secs to open. Does anyone know of a file comparison tool similar to kdiff3 that is fast on m1?

Comment: I just tried, the delay happens only the first time (as it should be). Do you really get the delay each time you run the application.

Comment: A KDE app that launches in only 3 seconds and it's a problem?

Comment: @nohillside yeah it isn't getting delayed each time, I just reacted based on the initial load time time. Later, it just stays open so it doesn't take much time.

Comment: The M1 optimized VSCode (pretty heavy) takes just a second to open so I've gotten too used to close to 0 initial load times.

Comment: As I said, I got the delay the first time I started it. Any later start was basically instant.

Comment: So I don't think your assumption about it having a 3 second delay each time is correct

Answer (score 5):

A app called FileMerge is included with [Apple's Xcode developer tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). It's a GUI app with a command-line variant called `opendiff`. FileMerge is optimized for M1 Macs. If you install Xcode, you'll find FileMerge at the path shown below and in the screenshot (it's a quick Spotlight search away as well):
*/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app*

[image: FileMerge location]

Comment: Great! However, you don't seem able to drop 2 files on FileMerge for comparison. It's a bit cumbersome to use.